# Python XML building

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to build an xml from python, how to loop in the sub elements?
I have been trying to get it in the format needed but cannot figure out how

The output I am getting  is this:

```
b'<member x0="28.921" y0="710.377" text="1. Case gdfh "><sub/></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="695.792" text="Version "> 0</sub></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="688.112" text="AER Number "> 4735986</sub></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="680.792" text="Initial Unit "> SBFBKJSF</sub></member>'
b'<member x0="28.921" y0="561.937" text="2. Patient"><sub/></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="510.697" text="Patient Information"></sub></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="496.112" text="Age "> 60 Years</sub></member>'
b'<member><sub x0="54.721" y0="488.432" text="Height "> 171 Centimeter</sub></member>'
```

The output I want is this:

```
b'
<member x0="28.921" y0="710.377" text="1. Case gdfh ">
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="695.792" text="Version "> 0</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="688.112" text="AER Number "> 4735986</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="680.792" text="Initial Unit "> SBFBKJSF</sub>
</member>
<member x0="28.921" y0="561.937" text="2. Patient">
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="510.697" text="Patient Information"></sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="496.112" text="Age "> 60 Years</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="488.432" text="Height "> 171 Centimeter</sub>
</member>
'
```

The code I'm writing is this:

Here, 'st' is the list of objects

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml


root = etree.Element('root')

for j in st:
    member = etree.SubElement(root, 'member')
    submbr = etree.SubElement(member, 'sub')

    if j.x0 == '28.921':
        root.append(member)
        member.append(submbr)
        member.attrib['x0'] = j.x0
        member.attrib['y0'] = j.y0
        member.attrib['text'] = j.text[0]
        member.text = j.text[1]
    else:
        submbr.attrib['x0'] = j.x0
        submbr.attrib['y0'] = j.y0
        submbr.attrib['text'] = j.text[0]
        submbr.text = j.text[1]



    out = etree.tostring(member)
    print(out)
```

The data structure , the st list when looped through has these values

```
TEXT                   x0       y0 
['1. Case gdfh ', ''] 28.921 , 710.377
['Version ', ' 0', ''] 54.721 , 695.792
['AER Number ', ' 4735986', ''] 54.721 , 688.112
['Initial Unit ', 'SBFBKJSF ', ''] 54.721 , 680.792
['2. Patient', ''] 28.921 , 561.937
['Patient Information', ''] 54.721 , 510.697
['Age ', ' 60 Years', ''] 54.721 , 496.112
['Height ', ' 171 Centimeter', ''] 54.721 , 488.432
```

Comment: Please also include the data structure that matches your sample (the `st` variable, but only the necessary part), so people don't have to make that up in order to provide tested code in an answer.

Comment: That being said, your `if:` body and your `else:` are equal. There is no need to have an if/else when you do the same thing in either case anyway.

Comment: Without else: , it gives a different output, doesnt includes the values of submember

Comment: Ahh, seeing the input data makes it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a new `member` every time the value of `x0` equals `'28.921'`, and in any other case you want to add a sub-member to whatever the *current* `member` is - unless there is no current member, which can happen when the first item in `st` is not `x0 == '28.921'`.

```
from lxml import etree

class betterdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

st = [
    betterdict({'text': ['1. Case gdfh ', ''],              'x0': '28.921', 'y0': '710.377'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['Version ', ' 0', ''],             'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '695.792'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['AER Number ', ' 4735986', ''],    'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '688.112'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['Initial Unit ', 'SBFBKJSF ', ''], 'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '680.792'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['2. Patient', ''],                 'x0': '28.921', 'y0': '561.937'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['Patient Information', ''],        'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '510.697'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['Age ', ' 60 Years', ''],          'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '496.112'}),
    betterdict({'text': ['Height ', ' 171 Centimeter', ''], 'x0': '54.721', 'y0': '488.432'}),
]

root = etree.Element('root')
member = None

for j in st:
    if j.x0 == '28.921':
        member = etree.SubElement(root, 'member')
        member.attrib['x0'] = j.x0
        member.attrib['y0'] = j.y0
        member.attrib['text'] = j.text[0]
    elif member is not None:
        submbr = etree.SubElement(member, 'sub')
        submbr.attrib['x0'] = j.x0
        submbr.attrib['y0'] = j.y0
        submbr.attrib['text'] = j.text[0]
        submbr.text = j.text[1]

out = etree.tostring(root)
print(out)
```

prints exactly what you want (formatted for readability)

```xml
<root>
  <member x0="28.921" y0="710.377" text="1. Case gdfh ">
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="695.792" text="Version "> 0</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="688.112" text="AER Number "> 4735986</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="680.792" text="Initial Unit ">SBFBKJSF </sub>
  </member>
  <member x0="28.921" y0="561.937" text="2. Patient">
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="510.697" text="Patient Information"></sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="496.112" text="Age "> 60 Years</sub>
    <sub x0="54.721" y0="488.432" text="Height "> 171 Centimeter</sub>
  </member>
</root>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, but the above code doesn't work., tried it

Comment: @user12637176 The update to your question showed how your input data is shaped. It does not show your input data (i.e. it's not Python code that I could run to get the same data structure you have). For example `'28.921'` will never be equal to `28.921`. The one is a string, the other is a number. Your data looks like it has numbers. Your code sample treats it as a string. Which of it is it? Again, there is no way for me to post tested code when you don't supply actual input to test on.

Comment: @user12637176 So I have made up a data structure that might or might not be what you have, but it shows that the code definitely works.

Comment: Yes..it is a string , i match the string and the data is in list form not dictionary, as the data is repetitive, i cannot use dictionary

Comment: @user12637176 I've shown you a solution that works. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @user12637176 Great, thanks for the feedback! (Please also mark the answer as accepted when you've used it to solve your issue.)

Comment: Done that, Thank you so much again! :)